# Reference counting Java

Tags: java, reference

Consider the following java code:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
}

Person p1 = new Person();
Person p2 = new Person();
Person p3 = p2;
p3 = p1;
```

How many total objects and reference variables are created here? Is `name` created even though it was never instantiated? 2 Objects are created but are there 3 or 5 reference variables?

Comment: Only `new` creates objects, and each `new` always creates exactly one object.

Comment: Right I understand the objects part, the reference variables are what confuses me. 3 are created in the bottom portion, since String is a reference variable are those created as well?

Comment: Uninitialized object fields default to `null`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: That's not always true; consider e.g. `Integer foo = 17000`, or `String bar = "" + foo`. (And, of course, even when there is a `new`, it's often buried deep in some compiled method call somewhere, rather than readily visible in the source-code you can see.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 objects are initialised, `p1` and `p2`.
`String name` will default to `null` but has a reference, so 2 references, one per instantiation of `Person`.
`int` is a primitive and will default to 0, nothing objecty going on here.
`p3` is a reference.
The last line is assignment, nothing created here.

The answer is 5.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are saved in the memory on a stack together with the primitive types for example. The objects are saved on the heap, so when creating for example:

Person p1 = new Person() on the stack p1 will be saved and on the heap memory the memory for the object Person will be allocated. The p1 from the stack will have a reference on the place allocated on the heap. On heap we allocate memory for example for the attributes like name or for the methods within the class. When just declaring a variable of person, the variable is saved only on stack so no new memory is allocated on the heap.

What happens when we do Person p3 = p2?
It will allocate memory on the stack for our variable and it will just add a reference to the place where p2 is saved.

For your example in the end we'll have 3 spots allocated (for p1, p2, p3) and on the heap we'll have only 2 spots allocated (for p1 and p2). p3 will have first reference to p2 and the will have reference to p1. In total we'll have 3 references created from stack to heap for the objects p1, p2, p3 and then we'll have 2 references for the String. In total we'll have 5 references.

Answer (score -1):

Two objects(`p1`, `p2`) three variables(`name`, `age`, `p3`).